# How to use OpenGL-ES 2.0 in linux and Android

Tags: android, linux, opengl-es-2.0

HI

I am having a ubuntu 10.10 enable laptop . I have run examples of OpenGL-ES 2.0  on Ubuntu 10.10 . now I want to run the codes in Android platform . How would I proceed .

Maybe I have to run android on ubuntu 10.10 and then run in the android but I don't know how to do that .

The thing is that I want to run the codes on Android in Ubuntu enable laptop.
if anyone is having suggestions .Please let me know this.

Sudhanshu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html): it is all perfectly explained there for any Operating system. Just follow the steps and you will get there.

One important point though, pick a minimum of API Level 8 for your project when you get there because [the OpenGL ES bindings for 2.0 were only added then](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html#api).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to run OpenGL-ES2.0 on ubuntu 10.10 . Actually we need an emulator to run it on PC embeded with Linux(Ubuntu 10.10).You can get that emulator here [here](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp)

You just download it and there is a documentation in it how to run and compile.
Maybe you still not able to compile it because it needs graphic drivers enables and mesa libraries. If you are not able to run it tell me I may tell you where are you wrong.